# how to use res.send in Express to send data to client to make ajax call with jQuery

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express

so, I have a newsletter form that I want to display a message under after the post request is done, I tried doing this using jQuery ajax call. I do a res.send("OK") in my server side but that res.send shows in the browser and I don't want it to show I just want it to be sent to the client so I can handle the request.

Here's the code:

index.js

```
router.post("/newsletter", (req, res) => {
    let newsletterEmail = req.body.newsletterEmail;
    console.log("Data: ", req.body.newsletterEmail);

    let mailOptions = {
        from: newsletterEmail,
        to: "myemail@email.com",
        subject: " Newsletter",
        html: "<h3>Newsletter Contact Email: " + newsletterEmail + "</h3>"
    }

    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, response) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
            res.status(500);
        } else {
            console.log("Successfully sent email.");
            res.send("OK");
        }
    })
})
```

main.js

```
// Newsletter Form
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/newsletter",
    data: $("#newsletterEmail"),
    success: function(msg){
      if (msg == "OK") {
        $("#success-sub-msg").css("opacity", "1");
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: *res.send shows in the browser* where exactly?

Comment: it just shows a blank page with OK in the top left corner.

Comment: Most probably an issue with the `smtpTransport` middleware..do you get this issue if you simply send a `res.send` without doing anything else?

Comment: _res.send shows in the browser_, after submitting the form? if this is the case, `preventDefault()` and try again.

Comment: @Abdus yes, res.send shows in the browser after submitting the form.
I used the same exact method with the middleware and ajax in the contact form and I had no issues what so ever.

Comment: you need to stop page reload on form submission. You can do that using `formNode.addEventListener('submit', e => {e.preventDefault(); /* ajax stuffs here */ })`

Comment: Thank you that totally worked.